# Dynamically generating Hudson custom workspace path

Tags: build, hudson

I'm trying to get a Hudson job to get built in a custom workspace path that is automatically generated using `yyyyMMdd-HHmm`. I can get the `$BUILD_ID` variable expanded as mentioned in [bug 3997](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-3997), and that seems to work fine. However, the workspace path is incorrect as it is of the format `yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss`. I've tried using the ZenTimestamp plugin v2.0.1, which changes the `$BUILD_ID`, but this only seems to take effect after the workspace is created.

Is there a method of defining a custom workspace in the manner that I want it?

Comment: Why do you need a custom workspace in the first place?

Comment: It's a side effect of our build architecture. Right now I build in the default workspace and then copy out to a folder named yyyyMMdd-HHmm. I'm trying to cut some build times by not having to do the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a groovy script to achieve that.

```
import hudson.model.*;
import hudson.util.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

//Part 1 : Recover build parameter
AbstractBuild currentBuild = (AbstractBuild) Thread.currentThread().executable;
def envVars= currentBuild.properties.get("envVars");
def branchName = envVars["BRANCH_NAME"];

//Part 2 : Define new workspace Path
def newWorkspace = "C:\\Build\\"+branchName;

//Part 3 : Change current build workspace
def newWorspaceFilePath = new FilePath(new File(newWorkspace));
currentBuild.setWorkspace(newWorspaceFilePath);
```